# Загрузка картинки в определенный столбец ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml

Не получается загружать картинку из ресурсов в нужный столбец. В столбце ничего не отображается, хотя конвертер отдаёт картинку. Где-то с биндами не домудрил?

```
<Window 
    x:Class="TestListViewReport.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:TestListViewReport"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="lv_report">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <c:StateImageConverter x:Key="StateImageConverter" />
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Width="32" Height="32" Source="{Binding Path=State, Converter={StaticResource StateImageConverter}}"></Image>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ItemName}" Header="Задача" Width="128" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=State}" Header="Статус" Width="64" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="1" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click">_Закрыть</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>


namespace TestListViewReport
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(TaskState), typeof(Image))]
    public class StateImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            switch ((TaskState)value)
            {
                case TaskState.done :
                    return Properties.Resources.Done;
                case TaskState.error:
                    return Properties.Resources.Error;
                case TaskState.waiting:
                    return Properties.Resources.Waiting;
                case TaskState.working:
                    return Properties.Resources.Working;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

namespace TestListViewReport
{
    public class ListViewData
    {
        public ListViewData(string itemName, TaskState state)
        {
            _ItemName = itemName;
            _State = state;
        }

        private string _ItemName;
        public string ItemName
        {
            get
            {
                return _ItemName;
            }
        }
        private TaskState _State;
        public TaskState State
        {
            get
            {
                return _State;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var data = new ListViewData("Задача 1", TaskState.done);
    lv_report.Items.Add(data);
}
```

Comment: (1) А какого типа ваш `Properties.Resources.Done`? (2) Что показывает окно Output насчёт failed bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы делаете неправильно. В WPF не принято упаковывать картинки в resx-файл. Кроме того, картинки в resx — это `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, которые не являются `ImageSource`.

Делайте так:

1. Заведите каталог в проекте, добавьте туда картинки, установите им Build Action = Resource. Таким образом, они будут помещены в WPF-специфические ресурсы.
2. Допустим, ваш каталог `Images`, а картинка — `done.png`. Поскольку вы привязываетес к свойству [`Source`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), имеющему тип `ImageSource`, то вам нужно получить валидный `ImageSource` на эту картинку. Это делается при помощи pack URI:

   ```
   var src = new BitmapImage();
   src.BeginInit();
   src.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Images/done.png");
   src.EndInit();
   ```

   Не забудьте подставить правильное имя сборки вместо `AssemblyName`! (Например, `TestListViewReport`.)